# Unrecongnized Selector name

Tags: ios, swift

Unrecognized Selector to instance name.

I want to create partion array from section. I am trying to do this in swift 2, but I am not able to get it to work.

```
     var currentCollation : UILocalizedIndexedCollation!
        var sections: [Section] {
            let selector: Selector = "name"

            let users: [User] = array.map { name in
                let a = name["fullName"] as? String
                let b = name["email"] as! String
                let c = name["mobile"] as! String
                let d = name["img"] as! String
                let user = User(name: a! )
                user.email = b
                user.mobile = c
                user.img = d


                user.section = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().section(for: user, collationStringSelector:"name")
                return user
            }

            var sections = [Section]()
            for _ in 0..<currentCollation.sectionIndexTitles.count {
                sections.append(Section())
            }
            for user in users {
                sections[user.section!].addUser(user: user)

            }


            print(sections)
            for section in sections {

               print(section.users)
                var user = section.users as? User
                print(user?.name)
            section.users = self.currentCollation.sortedArray(from: section.users, collationStringSelector: "name") as! [User]
            }
            return sections

        }

@objc class User: NSObject {
    let name: String
    var section: Int?
    var img: String?
    var email: String?
    var mobile : String?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}
 class Section {
    var users: [User] = []
    func addUser(user: User) {
        self.users.append(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: you have any method called `name`??

Comment: Please, when you post a question about an error, always include the complete and exact error message and point out the line causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strings for selectors in Swift. Use the `#selector` construct:

```
let selector: Selector = #selector(name)
```

However, that will only work if the current class is an NSObject and has an Objective-C function "name" that has no parameters:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc func name() {
        print("In \(#function)")
    }
}
```

(Actually, you **can** create a selector to an object that doesn't inherit from NSObject, but you can't use functions like `perform()` on such a selector, so it isn't very useful)

You don't appear to have a function named "name" in your class, of type `@objc` or not.

Comment: the OP is using a apple method that takes a selector name as a string! .. can we convert #selector to objc NSString.. maybe he could use `NSStringFromSelector(#selector(name))`

Comment: Yes, I realize that the OP is using a method that takes a selector name as a `String`. The new `#selector` construct is strongly preferred, since the compiler is able to do compile-time validation of the selector.